# xml/parse: Convert all tag names into lower case and remove empty row

Tags: xml, parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have a messy XML file and would like to standardize it by:

1. converting all tag names into lower case. For example, convert `<ROW>`, `<Year>` into `<row>`, and `<year>`
2. removing empty rows such like the empty space after `<ROW>` and before `</ROW>` tags.

I can do this in `BeautifulSoup` by calling:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_str_update, "lxml")
```

However, once the file is larger than certain size, `BeautifulSoup` begin to complain...

```
Exception MemoryError: MemoryError() in 'lxml.etree._BaseErrorLog._receive' ignored
```

So, I am wondering if this can be done using other library. Thanks in advance!

#### Sample of my xml file:

```
xml_str = """
<DATA>

    <ROW>
        <assmtid>1</assmtid>
        <Year>1988</Year>
    </ROW>

    <ROW>
        <assmtid>2</assmtid>
        <Year>1989</Year>
    </ROW>

    <ROW>
        <assmtid>2</assmtid>
        <Year>1990</Year>
    </ROW>

</DATA>
"""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT is your friend. You've described two transformation rules:

1. converting all tag names into lower case. For example, convert `<ROW>`, `<Year>` into `<row>`, and `<year>`

That's:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{lower-case(name())}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

2. removing empty rows such like the empty space after `<ROW>` and before `</ROW>` tags.

That's simply

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="ROW"/>
```

(or you can extend the list of elements you want this to apply to: `elements="*"` will strip whitespace-only text nodes from all elements).

If your document is more than a few hundred Mb then it will benefit from streaming, which is available in a couple of XSLT 3.0 processors - Saxon-EE and Exselt.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion!